# Finding company matches in a list of financial news

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with company ticker("ticker"), full name ("longName) and short name ("unofficial_name") - this abridged name is created from the long name by removing inc., plc...

I also have a seperate datefame with company news: date ("date" ) of the news, headline ("name"), news text ("text") and sentiment analysis.

I am trying to find company name matches in the list of articles and create a new dataframe with unique company-article matches (i.e. if one article mentions more than one company, this article would have more rows depending on the number of companies mentioned).

I tried to execute the matching based on the "unofficial_name" with the following code:

```
dict=[]

for n, c in zip(df_news["text"], sp500_names["unofficial_name"]):
    if c in n:
        x = {"text":n, "unofficial_name":c}
        dict.append(x)
        
print(dict)
```

But I get an empty list returned. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Could you share your data sample, please? We need some rows of your data to better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

sp500_names

```
 ticker  longName    unofficial_name 

0   A   Agilent Technologies, Inc.  Agilent Technologies 

1   AAL American Airlines Group Inc.    American Airlines Group
```

df_news

```
 name    date    text    neg neu pos compound

0   Asian stock markets reverse losses on global p...   2020-03-01  [By Tom Westbrook and Swati Pandey SINGAPORE (...   0.086   0.863   0.051   -0.9790 

1   Energy & Precious Metals - Weekly Review and C...   2020-03-01  [By Barani Krishnan Investing.com - How much ...    0.134   0.795   0.071   -0.9982
```

Thank you!